# Match based on a field only with non-empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a filter on something. Here is a simplified layout of my `Order` model:

```
{
    merchant: <Reference to the merchant>,
    date: <Date Object>
    name: "Some order name",
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: {data: "some data"}
        otherData: "some data"
    }]
}
```

I want to query the documents based on the ingredients that they contain.  I have an array of items to search through "objectifiedIngredients". If it has ingredients in it, then I want to search for orders that contain that ingredient. If the array is empty, then I want to not do the query and just get all orders.  "objectifiedIngredients" is a list of ObjectId's. Here is what I have so far:

```
      Order.aggregate([
            {$match:{
                merchant: new ObjectId(req.session.user),
                date: {
                    $gte: from,
                    $lt: to
                },
                ingredients: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        ingredient: {
                            $in: objectifiedIngredients
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}
        ])
```

How can I run the `$match` on ingredients only if the array has elements in it? I have tried using `$cond`, but either it doesn't work here or I didn't use it right.

Comment: Try `ingredients: {$ne: []}` Or do you mean `ingredients: {$in: objectifiedIngredients}`?

Comment: Hey, I made a mistake in my model.  It's updated now.  What I am trying to do is basically like you would think of a typical filter.  If the user chooses a few ingredients to search, they will search only those ingredients.  If they choose nothing, it shows everything.  Similarly, if the array is empty, don't do the $elemMatch on ingredients at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
Order.aggregate([
            {$match:{
                merchant: new ObjectId(req.session.user),
                date: {
                    $gte: from,
                    $lt: to
                },
                ingredients: {
                    $ne: false
                }
            }}
        ])
```

You can check for more details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/)

Comment: The issue with this is that I am trying to get all orders that contain any of the ingredients listed in `objectifiedIngredients`.  But if `objectifiedIngredients` is empty then it should return all orders and basically ignore the ingredients query.

Comment: Hey, I double checked and I was mistaken.  What I had did not work correctly.  Your query mostly works correctly.  For this, creating my query variable with {$ne: false} instead of {$exists: false} works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out after some time.  I didn't use Mongoose to solve it.  What I did was to create JavaScript variables to store the queries that I wanted.  So I used an if statement to set what query was stored.

```
let query = {};
if(objectifiedIngredients.length === 0){
    query = {$exists: true};
}else{
    query = {
        $elemMatch: {
            ingredient: {
                $in: objectifiedIngredients
            }
        }
    }
}

Order.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        merchant: new ObjectId(req.session.user),
        date: {
            $gte: from,
            $lt: to
        },
        ingredients: query
])
```

NOTE: the `{$exists: true}` part assumes that the ingredient array exists on the order.  If it doesn't then it won't return that order.